# Making a button rotate in XAML in a WPF form

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I need to make a Button rotate when pressed, but I cannot sem to figure out what's wrong with my code. I just started using XAML today so it's probably something very obvious.
When I run my code I get this error at runtime:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Het initialiseren van System.Windows.Controls.Button heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt. regelnummer 63 en >regelpositie 15.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<Button x:Name="ArrowButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" Height="360">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="UpArrow">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
Storyboard.TargetName="UpArrow"  
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" 
RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00CDCDCD"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
    <Image Source="upArrow.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="360" Width="360" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: `Button` or `Image` inside button?

Comment: @dkozl I tried to rotate the Button, but the image inside is circular, so that would also work without cutting of part of the image

Comment: *just started using XAML today* I hope you have had time reading about many other advanced and important concepts of WPF before writing some XAML code.

Comment: I don't see any element named `"UpArrow"` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problems is that you try to rotate target `UpArrow` and there is no element with such name so name your `Image`

```
<Image x:Name="UpArrow" ... />
```

second problem is that you use `TransformGroup` so you need to specify `Transform` you want to animate

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="UpArrow"  
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
    From="0" 
    To="360" 
    Duration="0:0:2" 
    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
```

so your XAML should look something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="ArrowButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" Height="360">
   <Button.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation 
                  Storyboard.TargetName="UpArrow"  
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                  From="0" 
                  To="360" 
                  Duration="0:0:2" 
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </Button.Triggers>
   <Button.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
         <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
         <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB"/>
         <GradientStop Color="#00CDCDCD"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Button.Background>
   <Image 
      x:Name="UpArrow" 
      Source="upArrow.png" 
      Stretch="Fill" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
      Height="360" 
      Width="360" 
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Image.RenderTransform>
         <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
         </TransformGroup>
      </Image.RenderTransform>
   </Image>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice when making animation, don't try to figure how to that in code! you have blend for that. (When you are making graphics you don't draw them by code you do that by drawing, same as animation) Only when really needed, edit your code to add a finish touch.

Just used blend for the job:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="UpArrow">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-360"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ArrowButton">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Row="0">
    <Button x:Name="ArrowButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image x:Name="UpArrow" Width="30" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```